# Exclude raw/ or specific files in raw/ during release build

Tags: android, ant

Is there a way to exclude certain files in raw/ or the entire raw/ directory itself, when making a release build? I use ant to compile—can I add something into my build script, which relies on the standard Android build script, to exclude raw/ files based on a pattern match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an ant [Move Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) to move your raw directory into some temporary folder and then another Move Task to move it back after you're done building.